# Tedious differential equation, any tips?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say i have an equation like this one:

$\nu''+3\nu'=e^x(x^3-1)$

I have tried to search a particular solution using one of tose:
$(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)\lambda e^x$

Calculus are tedious, there must be another way!

Comment: What are the exponents $I$ and $II$?

Comment: @Bernard First and second derivative

Comment: So, you're asking for $y''+y'=e^x(x^3-1)$?

Comment: That’s the most strait forward method. Sometimes math just takes a bit of grit.

Comment: If you rewrite as $(y'+3y)'=e^x(x^3-1)$, try to calculate, by parts, $\int e^x(x^3-1) dx$

Comment: Why do you have a $\lambda$ term?

Comment: @Joel is the most straight foward method but your answer must have only two remaining constants (not 5)

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Is legit to use this method?

Comment: @Andrei because im not sure if will be $\lambda=1$

Comment: the solution is given by $$y(x)=-c_1 e^{-x}+c_2+\frac{1}{8} e^x \left(4 x^3-18 x^2+42
   x-49\right)$$

Comment: How can you get $\lambda$? You will always get equations involving $a\lambda$, $b\lambda$, and so on. You can rewrite your solution as $(Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D)e^x$

Comment: @Andrei oh, you are saying that i can just include that $\lambda$ in the coefficients $A, B, C, D$, yeah, sounds legit. Bye Bye lambda.

Comment: One less thing to worry about

Comment: Well, the theory of ODE actually provides a formula for a special solution of $y''+by'+cy=g(x)$. Specifically, $$e^{\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}x}\int_0^xdu\, e^{u\sqrt{b^2-4c}}\int_0^ue^{\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}t}g(t)\,dt$$ And, as you can see, it is not as much a matter of calculations as it is a matter of finding a symbolic representation for the antiderivative of an antiderivative. Half of the time this is tedious, half of the time it is *nigh* impossibile and half of the time it is *actually* impossible.

Comment: You can let $\nu(x)=e^xy(x)$, so that $\nu''(x)+3\nu'(x)=e^x(y''(x)+5y'(x)+4y(x))$, which means $y$ solves $
y''+5y'+4y=x^3-1.
$  This is a little less tedious.

Comment: @user254433: obtaining the particular solution will again require multiplication with some exponential and then integration. So it does not appear much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to linear differential equation with constant coefficients can be done without any tricks following the standard procedure. And guessing the particular solution is not the right approach. The particular solution needs to be obtained directly. Just integrate your equation to get $$\nu'+3\nu=(x^3-3x^2+6x-7)e^x+c$$ and multiplying by $e^{3x}$ we get $$(\nu e^{3x})'=(x^3-3x^2+6x-7)e^{4x}+ce^{3x}$$ and integrating this one more time you get your $\nu$. Integration of a product of polynomial and exponential is particularly easy and can be done almost mechanically. Thus $$\nu e^{3x}=ce^{3x}+\frac{x^3-3x^2+6x-7}{4}e^{4x}-\frac{3x^2-6x+6}{16}e^{4x}+\frac{6x-6}{64}e^{4x}-\frac{6}{256}e^{4x}+d$$ or $$\nu=c+de^{-3x}+e^{x}\left(\frac{1}{4}x^3-\frac{15}{16}x^2+\frac{63}{32}x-\frac{427} {128}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a first order ODE in disguise. Let $y (x)=\nu'(x) $ and then apply an integrating factor. You still get a tedious integration by parts but it is very direct. Then just integrate your result once more to recover $\nu (x) $